# Add Event listener for Click/change on Bootstrap radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a shop filter and I need to dynamically get the value of the radio button that has been selected and execute a filter function with the value as a parameter.

my HTML is

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle pl-2" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
        <input type="radio" name="option_all" id="option_gender" autocomplete="off" value="All" checked=""> Unisex
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="option_man" id="option_gender" autocomplete="off" value="Male"> Man
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="option_woman" id="option_gender" autocomplete="off" value="Female"> Woman
    </label>
</div>
```

My idea was something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#option_gender').click(function(){
        filtefFunction(this.value)
    });
});
```

or an 
`addEventListener('click' func())` to  each radio  button ... but i dont know how can i do this.

I prefer of the solution is in vanilla js, because I'm trying to advance my  sills in it :) thank you

Comment: Your use of Bootstrap classes is all wrong to begin with. Take a look at their [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) when you can. Also, your inputs need to have the same name attribute if you plan on using their values on your server language later.

Comment: The id attribute only works when a single element in the page has it, by the way. So each radio id should be like "option_gender1", "option_gender2" and "option_gender3" for example.

Answer (score 4):

What I prefer to do in cases like this is to delegate an event to the parent container:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('gender-selection');

select.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => { // handler fires on root container click
  if (target.getAttribute('name') === 'option_gender') { // check if user clicks right element
    alert('Filter by: ' + target.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle pl-2" id="gender-selection" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label for="option_gender-unisex">Unisex</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option_gender" id="option_gender-unisex" value="All" checked="">

  <label for="option_gender-man">Man</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option_gender" id="option_gender-man" value="Male">

  <label for="option_gender-woman">Woman</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option_gender" id="option_gender-woman" autocomplete="off" value="Female">
</div>
```

As a sidenote you don't want to use same id's for different elements, on the other hand if you want your radio group allowing to select only one value — use same `name` attribute. Also `autocomplete` attribute is redundant for inputs of `radio` type. It won't do anything.

UPD: removed unnecessary loop from the handler.

Answer (score 2):

A few things, your input should have same name to group them together, and not use the same id. i have replaced your id with class.

```js
function getActive(){
 console.log( document.querySelector('.option_gender:checked').value );
}
document.querySelectorAll(".option_gender").forEach( input => input.addEventListener('click', getActive) );
```

```html
<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle pl-2" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
            <input type="radio" name="option" class="option_gender" autocomplete="off" value="All" checked=""> Unisex
          </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="option" class="option_gender" autocomplete="off" value="Male"> Man
          </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="option" class="option_gender" autocomplete="off" value="Female"> Woman
          </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variable to save **the value of the radio button that has been selected**

Try this:

```
var selectedGender;
function executeFilter(input) {
    // do filter
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.option_gender').click(function(){
        selectedGender = (this).attr('value'));
        executeFilter(selectedGender);
    });
});
```

You should give to each input a **class name**, **id** just match the first element!

Example:

```
<label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="option" class="option_gender" autocomplete="off" value="All" checked=""> Unisex
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//get NOD-object of clicking element
var button = document.getElementById('get_gender');
//method .onclick is prefer becouse not so much load the browser like EventListener
button.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();//this line stop send data to server
  console.log('hi');//this is work:) we check it
}
```

```html
<!--Replase name and id, becouse id is an unique name and proporty 'name' groupe radio-buttons -->
<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle pl-2" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
            <input type="radio" id="option_all" name="option_gender" autocomplete="off" value="All" checked=""> Unisex
          </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" id="option_man" name="option_gender" autocomplete="off" value="Male"> Man
          </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" id="option_woman" name="option_gender" autocomplete="off" value="Female"> Woman
          </label>

  <button id="get_gender">Click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you edit your radios so all of them have the same name, you assign a function to their `check` event so it only triggers when you change the input value.

```
$(document).on("check", "[name='option_gender']", function (){
    filterFunction($(this).val());
});
```